# Yii2 Webvimark method not allowed

Tags: yii2, webvimark

I am getting error yii2 when i am logging in it shows error first time and after next try login will work. the same problem is in delete user in webvimark user listing grid view.
so i am not getting whats the issue. any help will be appreciated.

Error :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you just need to update composer

```
composer update
```